# Completely disable "close lid" key binding

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I have acer aspire e13 es1-311-c6bx. When I close the lid it wakes up from sleep, be it by clicking to sleep or setting closeLid=sleep in power options, and touchpad is not working anymore.

I can not recover touchpad afterwards (though `sudo rmmod psmouse ; sudo modprobe psmouse` works some times) unless i reboot (fn+f7 touchpad doesnt revive the touchpad, but disables/enables it perfectly before I close the lid). Actually touchpad is disabled even if I don't sleep the laptop(closeLid=doNothing in power options and just close the lid and open again). Sleep works find as long as the laptop's lid is not closed. If I quickly close and open the lid with closeLid=sleep it will start the sleep and continue sleeping with the lid open, the power light indicator shows that wakeup is always after 1 second of sleep.The touchpad is not disabled if I sleep using the mouse and close lid.

I can only think that close lid binding is set up as a wake key (any key from keyboard, but not touchpad and external mouse will wake laptop) and it disables the touchpad(probably as an energy saving method). But because the laptop doesn't have a lid open "key" it doesn't restore the touchpad on "lid open".

How can I completely disable this binding?

Tried to

```
look in /lib/udev/hwdb.d/ 
 for key bindings, but didn't find it
sudo showkey -k 
 but key is not registered
xev
 but the only thing I found was a "KeymapNotify event", don't think this helps
sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
 alter to HandleLidSwitch=ignore does not help
```

Ps completely disable as in disable the key as a wakeup from sleep method.
I would think that because windows 8.1 is capable of waking up and sleeping, means that linux should be able to do the same(not a hardware problem).

Answer (score 0):

on my es1-512 I  had to disable the xHCI usb 3.0 controller for that to work correctly. also it fixed the reboot and shutdown issue as well